# Change the collectionView cells layout on button click in swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, uikit

[image: 1] This is the main scenario which is a collection view and by pressing View button (highlighted in the image) i want to change the layout of cells like tableview cells shown in the 2nd picture.

**Result needed:**

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two `UICollectionViewLayout` objects, each with their layout options, and use [`setCollectionViewLayout(_:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618086-setcollectionviewlayout) to switch between the two.

Comment: do i have to make a new cell for it or what?
Can you share a piece of code which can help me?

Comment: That's up to you. You can return a different cell depending on the layout, or you can create your cells in a way that they adjust their content based on the layout.